# What is causing a ValueError in my RandomForestRegressor input data with no NaN values?

Tags: input, contains, valueerror

<kbd>[tag:[tag:`ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)  in <cell line: 11>() 9               'max_depth' : [3,5,10]} 10 ---> 11 results_grid = grid_search_forecaster( 12     forecaster = forecaster, 13     y = df1_train['sales'],]</kbd>

```
     No NaN values.
```

`np.all(np.isfinite(df1))`
True

```
  I tried
```

1. `df1_filter = df1.isin([np.nan, np.inf, -np.inf])`
2. ```
   df1 = df1[~df1_filter] df1.dropna(inplace=True)
   ```
3. `df1.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan, inplace=True) df1.dropna(inplace = True)`
    `3.`with `pd.option_context('mode.use_inf_as_na', True):`
   `` `df1.dropna(inplace=True) ``
   `print(df1)`

   Nothing works